# Is it necessary to install SQLite or it is pre installed in ANDROID?

Tags: android

Hello Everyone I'm really new bee in android and for that I'm confused to play with database. Let me come to the point, Actual I'm trying to save my form detail in database, but here I dnt know will I have to install database for that or it is installed while installing android SDK...
  Please HELP Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pre-installed - you can directly use it from your tools. THere is a way to store a pre-populated db in the assets/ folder that can then be copied over.

See also http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 0):

It comes with Android SDK and is located in /tools folder of your install!

You can add this folder to your PATH variable and thus open a database file from every command prompt!

But remember that there are Android ROMs which don't come with an SQLite Editor installed. You have to push the bin manually in that case.

Anyway, working with Databases from within your app will work on every ROM, cause that's a basic feature of the Android OS.

Answer (score 0):

It is already installed in Android device or emulator. You just have to create a new database for your application.